# Species ID of this giant brain-shaped mushroom? How do its spores escape, there's no "puff" for this puffball!

Tags: species-identification, mycology

After several days of rain then a few warm sunny days in northern Taiwan in August, I came across this giant mushroom growing in an open field that's only occasionally mowed.

This mushroom about 18 cm tall and the cap is 20 cm wide. The the very thick base is also 15 cm wide.

The color is beige and white. The cap is wrinkled giving the very rough appearance of a brain.

There were no obvious places for the spores to come out.

There were older ones that had fallen over and had turned dark brown to black.

They feel quite dense.

**Questions:**

1. Can this mushroom be identified?
2. How do its spores escape?

[image: ID this giant brain-shaped mushroom?]

---

Following up on the helpful comments I've gone back and taken some additional photos of other mushrooms in this large group.

The first was still white, the second had fallen over and turned brown.

I'm thinking that there is something wrong here, there's no evidence of a "puff" or big dramatic dispersal event. They just turn brown, fall over, then turn black.

It seems like a lot of work to go through to make such a huge puff ball, but then not really ever "puff"!

[image: giant brain-shaped puffball? mushroom]

[image: giant brain-shaped puffball? mushroom]

Comment: First google result for "brain shaped mushroom taiwan" suggests *Calvatia craniiformis*, which has variable morphology but many pics look similar to your specimen, e.g. https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/skull-puffball-species-giant-white-mushroom-1398120314

Comment: @Luigi *Thanks!* I've posted this for a friend, and since posting they've been searching in Chinese and come across both  *C. craniiformis* and  *C. lilacina* found [here](https://lindyeh.pixnet.net/blog/post/28713961). Looks like we're getting close. There is actually cooking instructions but I'm not going to be doing that :-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPtRs.jpg

Comment: https://www.marylandbiodiversity.com/view/4990

Comment: Puffballs break open when mature relapsing dust-like spores. When mature they are mostly hollow . When stepped on they make a puff of spore, I guess that is the source of the name.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I ran across this image      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Purchawka_olbrzymia_i_widelec.jpg of *[Calvatia gigantea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvatia_gigantea)* which is said to be a "puff ball" but certainly looks solid in cross-section, and the mushroom in my question feels quite dense and solid, even the ones that turn black, die and fall over intact. I think there's something different going on here. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Old_Giant_puffball_Calvatia_gigantea.jpg I don't have any photos of the dead mushrooms I saw near this one.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I'll try to add a photo of a dead, fallen-over mushroom in a day or two when I can get back there. In the mean time here are more cross-sectional images https://www.mushroomdiary.co.uk/2015/09/giant-puffball-calvatia-gigantea/ and also https://doorcountypulse.com/door-to-nature-mushrooms-galore/ There are plenty of slicking and cooking recommendations but I'm not going to be partaking in that.

Comment: "A giant puffball is edible if the inside is totally white and even-textured" It sounds like these are not hollow at all.

Comment: @uhoh all puffballs are solid when young, hollow when mature.

Comment: I found some record size giant puffballs ( like 18" diameter). fried a few slices in butter; tasted like fried butter .  So little or no flavor.

Comment: @jmster I've added some photos

Comment: @blacksmith37 ditto Do puffballs this big rely on being stepped-on to reproduce?

Comment: If this is indeed a giant puffball, the puff comes out of tiny pores in the sporangium (the bit you see), especially as it rolls and breaks apart after maturity. IIRC one of the Attenborough doco's had great footage of this, possibly Private Life of Plants.